# Angular routing with login to Identity server

Tags: angular, identityserver4

I'm trying to setup Angular and Identity server. This app really on has two routes. project-list and project-details.

Both of these pages need to be secured. Right now it works somewhat. When I got to http://localhost:4200
It will show the project-list page with the header but no project data. After about a second or two it redirects to the Identity server login page.

I don't want it to show the project-list page with header, I want it to go straight to login page.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "project-list",
    component: ProjectlistComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard]
  },
  {
    path: "project-details/:id",
    component: ProjectDetailsComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard]
  },
  { 
    path: "", 
    redirectTo: "project-list", 
    pathMatch: "full" 
  }
```

In the AuthorizationGuard if the user is not authenticated redirect to autologin

```
  private checkUser(): any {
    console.log('AuthorizationGuard, canActivate');

    return this.oidcSecurityService.getIsAuthorized().pipe(
      tap((isAuthorized: boolean) => {
        console.log('AuthorizationGuard, canActivate isAuthorized: ' + isAuthorized);        

        if (!isAuthorized) {
          this.router.navigate(['/autologin']);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Is there a better way without redirecting to Autologin?

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { OidcSecurityService } from "angular-auth-oidc-client";

@Component({
  selector: "app-auto-component",
  templateUrl: "./auto-login.component.html"
})
export class AutoLoginComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  lang: any;

  constructor(public oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService) {
    this.oidcSecurityService.onModuleSetup.subscribe(() => {
      this.onModuleSetup();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.oidcSecurityService.moduleSetup) {
      this.onModuleSetup();
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {}

  private onModuleSetup() {
    this.oidcSecurityService.authorize();
  }
}
```

Comment: try adding `canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard]` to the redirection for "project-list"

Comment: @Kevin no it's not needed, guards provided in the original route are good enough.

Comment: code looks good, please provide the implementation of `canActivate` in `AuthorizationGuard` too

Comment: canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.checkUser();
  }

Comment: I can see that you're redirecting the user but not returning `boolean` from `checkUser()` method, return `isAuthorized` and it should work fine. `if (!isAuthorized) {
          this.router.navigate(['/autologin']);
        } return isAuthorized`

Comment: If the user is not authorized, then I want to redirect to the autologin component. This routes them to the identity server.

It is working, but just a little slower than I expect and The header is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you `authgaurd` is returning `checkUser()` if not you have to.Then you have to return Boolean inside your pipe  so change your `checkUser()` to

```
private checkUser(): Observable<bool>{
     return this.oidcSecurityService.getIsAuthorized().pipe(
      map((isAuthorized: boolean) => {
        if (!isAuthorized) {
          this.router.navigate(['/autologin']);
        }
        return isAuthorized;
      })
    );
  }
```